# Rally SDK - Fetch all projects under a workspace and create Iteration

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am new to Rally Custom App development. I have created a Custom Html app that will create multiple Iterations in Rally. Currently this app works great in a single project under a workspace however I need some help to expand this code to create iterations in all the projects under a workspace. Kind of bulk iteration creation and cascade to all child projects under a parent.Could you please share some inputs?

```
                   var record = Ext.create(this.model, {
                         Name: 'Sprint' + ' ' + Itnumber,
                         StartDate: stdt1,
                        EndDate: enddt,
                        State: 'Planning'
                    });

                    record.save({
                        callback: function (result, operation) {
                            if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                //Get the new defect's objectId
                                var objectId = result.get('ObjectID');
                              //  alert(objectId);
                            }
                            else
                                console.log(operation.getError());
                                //alert("Error in saving :" +operation.getError());
                        }
                    });

                    stdt1 = Ext.Date.add(new Date(enddt), Ext.Date.DAY, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cascade=true` for both Releases and Iterations to create matching timeboxes in child projects.

```
record.save({
    params: {
        cascade: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Kyle and Katie. Your solution worked great. Appreciate your great help.